# How to tell if a C# project is being built using SSD?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, solid-state-drive

I have a laptop with such setup, a big c# project is located on disk D:

[image]

How do I tell if when building it, SSD is used? Or, ***what*** is used? RAM?...
I first build it from command line, and when I open Visual Studio, I can build from there again.

I realize this might be a newbie question so please don't throw things at me.

Comment: The build process is going to be done in the CPU and RAM.  So the only way an SSD comes into play is if that's where the files are located and you can determine that by just looking at the drive (as per the image you've posted).  Now if you're trying to write code that determines if a drive is a SSD then that would be on topic here, but what you have doesn't seem to be.

Comment: SSD only determines how fast files are read oer written (both compiler files and code files). There are no Visual Studio SSD optimization features

Comment: @juharr should I move this question to another forum? which one?

Comment: I'm not sure this wouldn't get closed on other sites as it's confusing.  What do you need to know beyond the image you posted?  It tells you both drives are SSD so there you go.

Comment: I did not know which parts of the computer are used for building the project, and if I need to do anything specific to make sure SSD is used.

Answer (score 0):

You can confirm or change your build output directory:
Right-click on the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties.
Select the Build tab.
Find the output path groupbox on the page

[Snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I5Yn.png)